# Some collection view cells do not auto rotate iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, ios13, screen-rotation

I have multiple collection views in a view and when I scroll and rotate the screen, some cells do not orient correctly according to the screen orientation.

Things I have tried:

1.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

2.

```
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        if let carousels = self.carouselViews {
            for carousel in carousels {
                carousel.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

                }) { (Bool) in

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Portrait:
[image: Portrait]

Landscape:
[image]